# Find instance following given element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about dom navigation with jquery. I'm trying to find an element with a given class that is closest in the dom following a given element.

I have a table like structure, created through divs and styled in css. I have an element being edited, and when the user presses enter I want to focus the following editable element. However, it's not a sibling of the element being edited.

**HTML**

```
<div class="calendarEntry">
  <div when="2014,9,18" class="when">Sep 18</div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        <div code="ABC" class="type">ABC123</div>
        <div offered="2014,9,15" class="offered dateish">Sep 15
            <div class="offer editable">10</div>
            <div class="sku editable">TH1</div>
            <button>Publish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div code="DEF" class="type">DEF321</div>
        <div offered="2014,9,14" class="offered dateish">Sep 14
            <div class="offer editable">10</div>
            <div class="sku editable">TH2</div>
            <button>Publish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div code="GHI" class="type">GHI852</div>
        <div offered="2014,9,12" class="offered dateish">Sep 12
            <div class="offer editable">10</div>
            <div class="sku editable">TH3</div>
            <button>Publish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: There are multiple calendar entries on the page.

Say the user is editing the offer of the DEF312 item. When they hit enter I want to edit the offer of GHI852. I have the code to make the div editable, by replacing it with a text field with a class of `offer editing`. If they're editing the final offer in this calendar entry, then the enter key should focus the first editable offer of the following calendar entry, if there is one. If we're at the bottom of the list I don't want to wrap back to the top (which I think would overly complicate matters anyway).

The bit I'm stuck with is how to find the next offer (all offers are editable).

Here's what I've tried:

```
var nextOffer = $('.offer').find('.editing').next('.editable');
```

Clearly, this doesn't work. The problem is that the following editable offer isn't a sibling of the current offer being edited, so `next()` doesn't work for me. The following offer could be in the current calendar entry, or it's just as likely to be in the next calendar entry. Either way, it's a few divs away, at varying depths.

Can I even do this with jquery dom traversals, or am I better just brute forcing it through javascript (i.e. looping through all `.editable` instances and returning the one after `.editing`?

Comment: Have you tried using `.parent()` to get out of the current editable offer and into the next?

Comment: I think your problem is that "item" keeps getting nested deeper and deeper. The structure doesn't exactly follow a logical order.

Comment: Yeah, tried various combinations of parent() and parents(). Couldn't work it out.

Comment: That's a typo in my code here, I'll fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the class 'editing' to simulate the the input:

```
<div class="item">
        <div code="DEF" class="type">DEF321</div>
        <div offered="2014,9,14" class="offered dateish">Sep 14
            <div class="offer editable">10</div>
            <div class="sku editable editing">TH2</div>
            <button>Publish</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

you can do:

```
    function findEditable(currentItem) {

        var nextEditable = undefined,
            selectors = [".item", ".calendarEntry"];

        $.each(selectors , function (idx, selector) {

            var ref = currentItem.closest(selector);

            nextEditable = ref.parent()
                .children("div:gt(" + ref.index() + ")")
                .find(".offer.editable")
                .first();

            return nextEditable.length === 0;
        })


        return nextEditable;

    }

    findEditable($(".editing")).css({
        color: 'red'
    });
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FrankFuenmayor/r7gqx4zg/6/)

Comment: Thanks @frankfg, but the question says that the next editable offer may be in the next calendar-entry. Given that, the number of parent calls changes based on whether I'm editing the last offer in the current calendar-entry, or not.

Comment: Sorry, I hope the new proposal helps you.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't really looking for a brute-force javascript solution (because I could write one myself quite easily). I was looking for a jquery dom-navigation solution. However, this solution is the only one that works, and I can copy/paste it rather than write it myself, so I'll accept it -- thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parents()` to get the `.offered` element which contains the `.offer` element like so:

```
var offered = $('.offer').find('.editing').parents('.offered');
```

From that you can use `next()` to get into the `.offered` element's sibling `.item` element, and find the `.editable` element within that:

```
offered.next('.item').find('.editable');
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gudLfn35/)**. *Note that I've manually added this `.editing` element within your DEF321 item's `.offer` element - I assume this gets added dynamically on your side, but either way isn't included in your question.*

---

**Edit:** The HTML in the question has now been changed. Based on this, instead of getting the `.offered` parent, you'd get the `.item` parent:

```
var item = $('.offer').find('.editing').parents('.item');
```

And proceed in the same way as before:

```
item.next('.item').find('.editable');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gudLfn35/2/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really work for me. It doesn't deal with the fact that the next editable offer may be in a following calendar-entry.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I've updated my answer to reflect the change made to the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var current=document.activeElement,
    all=$(".editable"),
    index=all.indexOf(current),
    next=all[index+1]
```

It first finds the current element and the list of elements,
then it will find the current element in the list.
It will then add 1 to the index and select it from the list.

To extend the array with the indexOf function;

```
if(!Array.prototype.indexOf){
  Array.prototype.indexOf=function(e/*,from*/){
    var len=this.length>>>0,
        from=Number(arguments[1])||0;
    from=(from<0)?Math.ceil(from):Math.floor(from);
    if(from<0)from+=l;
    for(;from<len;from++){
      if(from in this&&this[from]===e)return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I get an error in firefox indicating that indexOf isn't a function. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Maybe firefox lacks an array.indexOf function, try adding it via prototype. Example follows in a minute or so.